# How to re order this DataFrame in Python wthout hard coding column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df ('COL3 SUM' is the full name with a space):

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 SUM  COL4  COL5
   1     2       3     4     5
```

How can I re order this df so that 'COL3 SUM' always comes at the end of the dataframe like so without re ordering any of the rest of the df?

```
   COL1 COL2  COL4  COL5 COL3 SUM 
       1    2    4     5        3
```

Comment: what would be the rule? the column(s) with a space at the end? the column(s) containing sum at the end? always the third column at the end?

Comment: The column containing 'sum' at the end @Ben.T
I added the rule sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move all columns with some keyword e.g. `"SUM"` to the end:

- create list of unmoved columns
- append excluded columns to end
- reorder dataframe by calling on new column list

code:

```
new_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "SUM" not in col]
moved_cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(new_cols)) 
new_cols.extend(moved_cols)
df = df[new_cols]
```

output:

```
   COL1  COL2  COL4  COL5  COL3 SUM
0     1     2     4     5         3
```

Comment: works like a charm :) but is there a standard 'pandas' way of doing this? it seems like it should be relatively simple to just move a column with a keyword to the back

Comment: I would say its a reasonable method.  It's rare for operations to depend on column order, so methods to reorder them are generally not a first order concern of pandas

Answer (score 1):

`newDF = df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x:(" " in x,x))]`

would do it i think

if the only criteria is the space ... just use that as the only criteria

`newDF = df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x:" " in x]`

if its still changing the original order try

`newDF = df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x:(" " in x,list(df.columns).index(x))]`

this assumes the key bit is the space ... if its SUM just change what you are checking for

Comment: that returns  `newDF = df[sorted(df.columns,lambda x:(" " in x,x))]
TypeError: sorted expected 1 arguments, got 2`

Comment: Using this:

df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':[1,1,1], 'COL2':[2,2,2], 'COL3 SUM':[3,3,3], 'COL4':[4,4,4], 'COL5':[5,5,5]})
print(df)
df = df[sorted(df.columns,lambda x:(" " in x,x))]
print(df)

Comment: i left off key=

Comment: I shouldve used a different example df. I don't want the columns to be sorted in ascending order since the actual cols im working with have different names. I simply wanted the column with the key word to come at the end always without messing with the rest of the order

Comment: No cigar with the latest revision you made:


    `df = df[sorted(df.columns,key=lambda x:("SUM" in x,df.columns.index(x)))]
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: fixed... i guess i had to cast it to a list